# Unable to run python pip command

Tags: python, pip, typeerror, python-3.7

When I use the pip command `pip [options]` I get the following error everything, the only way to use pip seems to be `python -m pip [options]`

This error started happening after I added `--user` at the end of a pip command

I've tried uninstalling python and reinstalling, but it still won't work.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python375\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "e:\python375\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "E:\Python375\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Any help is appreciated.!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bpip%5d%20TypeError%3a%20%27module%27%20object%20is%20not%20callable

Comment: I think someone else _just_ posted about the same problem, [check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58685565/11301900), it might help.